# GLib handle out of memory

Tags: c, memory, glib

I've a question concerning the GLib.
I would like to use the GLib in a server context but I'm not aware on how the memory is managed:
https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Memory-Allocation.html

> If any call to allocate memory fails, the application is terminated. This also means that there is no need to check if the call succeeded.

If I look at the source code, if g_malloc failed, it will call g_error:

> g_error()
>
> ## define             g_error(...)
>
> A convenience function/macro to log an error message.
> Error messages are always fatal, resulting in a call to abort() to terminate the application.[...]

But in my case, as I'm developing a server application, I don't want the application exit, I would prefer, as the traditional malloc function, the GLib functions returns NULL or something to indicate an error happened.

So, my question is, there is a manner to handle out of memory?
Is the GLib not recommended for server purpose applications?

If I look at the man of abort I can see that I can handle the signal but I'll make the management of out-of-memory errors a little bit painful...

> The abort() function causes abnormal program termination to occur, unless
> the signal SIGABRT is being caught and the signal handler does not
> return.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: [It is not recommended to use GLib at all.](http://suckless.org/sucks/)

Comment: Or for an alternative opinion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4310227/2082884

Answer (score 3):

It's very difficult to recover from lack of memory. The reason for that is that it can be considered a terminal state, in the sense that lack of memory will persist for some time before it goes away. Even reacting to the lack of memory (like informing the user) might require more memory, for example, to build and send a message. A related problem is that there are operating systems (linux at least) that may be over optimistic about allocating memory. When the kernel realizes that memory is missing, it may kill the application, even if your code is handling the failures.

So either you have a much stricter grasp of your whole system than average, or you won't be able to successfully handle out of memory errors, and, in this case, it doesn't matter what the helper library is doing.

If you really want to control memory allocation while still using glib, you have partial ways to do that. Don't use any glib allocation function and use some from other library. Glib provides functions that receive a "free function" when necessary. For example:

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.31/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-hash-table-new-full

The hash table constructor accepts functions for destroying both keys and values. In your case, the data will be allocated using custom allocation functions, while the hash data structures will be allocated with glib functions.

Alternatively you could use g_try_* macros to allocate memory, so you still use glib allocator, but it won't abort on error. Again, this only partially solves the problem. Internally, glib will implicitly call functions that may abort and it assumes it will never return on error.

About the general question: does it make sense for a server to crash when it's out of memory ? The obvious answer is no, but I can't estimate how theoretical this answer is. I can only expect that the server system be properly sized for its operation and reject as invalid any input that could potentially exceed its capacities, and for that, it doesn't matter which libraries it might use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer hdante, I up-voted it. I understand that a lack of memory can be a terminal state for an application but in my situation the solution is quite simple, close the client experiencing the problem and free its resources. It should release some memory and other clients will may be able to continue to run.
I didn't know that Linux can kill your application without summation, that's weird.
In the core of the server (everything about socket management) I've a strict grasp of memory management. 
I wanted to use a library as GLib to accelerate the dev of the "business" part.

Comment: I disagree that it's difficult to recover from lack of memory.  What makes it hard is the Linux model of overcommit-by-default.  If you get into the mindset that malloc can return null and apply this throughout an entire code base it's very feasible.  Having worked with such a code base, I have not found it challenging, and in practice (as seen in the field) you can recover from it most of the time (and in a way that surfaces to the user, even).  Dismissing the problem as hard is a cop-out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably editorializing a bit here, but the modern tendency to use virtual/logical memory (both names have been used, although "logical" is more distinct) does dramatically complicate knowing when memory is exhausted, although I think one can restore the old, real-(RAM + swap) model (I'll call this the physical model) in Linux with the following in `/etc/sysctl.d/10-no-overcommit.conf`:

```
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
vm.overcommit_ratio = 100
```

This restores the ability to have the philosophy that if a program's `malloc` just failed, that program has a good chance of having been the actual cause of memory exhaustion, and can then back away from the construction of the current object, `free`ing memory along the way, possibly grumbling at the user for having asked for something crazy that needed too much RAM, and awaiting the next request.  In this model, most OOM conditions resolve almost instantly - the program either copes and presumably returns RAM, or gets killed immediately on the following SEGV when it tries to use the 0 returned by `malloc`.

With the virtual/logical memory models that linux tends to default to in 2013, this doesn't work, since a program won't find memory isn't available at `malloc`, but instead upon attempting to access memory later at which point the kernel finally realizes there's nowhere in RAM for it.  This amounts to disaster, since any program on the system can die, rather than the one the ran the host out of RAM.  One can understand why some GLib folks don't even care about trying to fix this problem, because with the logical memory model, it *can't* be fixed.

The original point of logical memory was to allow huge programs using more than half the memory of the host to still be able to fork and exec supporting programs.  It was typically enabled only on hosts with that particular usage pattern.  Now in 2013 when a home workstation can have 24+ GiB of RAM, there's really no excuse to have logical memory enabled at all 99% of the time.  It should probably be disabled by default on hosts with >4 GiB of RAM at boot.

Anyway.  So if you want to take the old-school physical model approach, make sure your computer has it enabled, or there's no point to testing your `malloc` and `realloc` calls.

If you *are* in that model, remember that GLib wasn't really guided by the same philosophy (see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=51286#c27 for just how madly astray some of them are).  Any library based on GLib *might* be infected with the same attitude as well.  However, there may be some interesting things one can do with GLib in the physical memory model by emplacing your own memory handlers with `g_mem_set_vtable()`, since you might be able to poke around in program globals and reduce usage in a cache or the like to free up space, then retry the underlying `malloc`.  However, that's limited in its own way by not knowing which object was under construction at the point your special handler is invoked.